# StateProvider gets updated but ref.listen does not triggers

Tags: flutter, riverpod, listen

I have a StateProvider defined in a file (separated from any class) as follow :

```
final XYProvider = StateProvider<List<double>>((ref) ( return [0.0,0.0]));
```

it gets updated like this (for the most part) :

```
ref.read(XYPosProvider.notifier).state[0] =

            (ref.read(currentXPosProvider.notifier).state -

                        ref.read(initialXPosProvider.notifier).state) *

                    80000 +

                39;
```

And in another file I want to call a method when the value is updated using

```
ref.listen() : 
void userPositionNodesMaker(List<double>? XYPos) {

      bool isInBoundaries(var _) {

        return _ > 0 && _ < (iMazeLength - 1);

      }



      setState(() {

        print(XYPos![0].round());

        print(XYPos[1].round());



        if (isInBoundaries(XYPos[0].round()) &&

            isInBoundaries(XYPos[1].round())) {

          mazeMatrix[XYPos[0].round()][XYPos[1].round()].setUserNode();

        }

      });

    }



    ref.listen(XYPosProvider, (List<double>? prev, List<double>? next) {

      print('XYPOSCHANGED');

      userPositionNodesMaker(next);

    });
```

This is placed in the Widget build of this ConsumerStatefulWidget and I dont under stand why it does not triggers. I have a button inside this Widget printing the value of XYPosProvider showing that it is well updated and acessed in my widget but still nothing happens in the ref.listen

Tried Notification but I did not have sucess trying to create a custom one instead of ScrollNotifications. Im looking on ChnageNotifier as an alternative for the moment but still I can’t figure out why ref.listen wouldn’t work.

Comment: StateProvider is only used to store and display simple variables. In the code you provided, StateNotifierProvider should be the correct provider to use.

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have to change the state of collections in an immutable way. For example, it goes like this:

```
final newState = ref.read(XYPosProvider.notifier).state;

newState = newState[0] = 
  ref.read(currentXPosProvider.notifier).state -
  (ref.read(initialXPosProvider.notifier).state * 80000 + 39);


// update state:
ref.read(XYPosProvider.notifier).state = [...newState];
// or 
ref.read(XYPosProvider.notifier).state = List.of(newState);
```

Comment: Thanks yes i didn't now the immutable aspect of StateProvider, so I switched to StateNotifierProvider it works well now !

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I switched to State**Notifier**Provider and it works just fine Here what I modified :

````
``` class XYPosNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<double>> {
  XYPosNotifier() : super([39, 20]);

  void updatePosition(double x, double y) {
    state = [x, y];
  }
}

final xyPosProvider = StateNotifierProvider<XYPosNotifier, List<double>> 
 ((ref) {
  return XYPosNotifier();
});
````

bit more heavy but really usefull even when updating it looks like this now :     `ref.read(xyPosProvider.notifier).updatePosition(x, y);`

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).